# How to set width auto in wizard modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I had tried to make modal wizard, in first modal it's width is perfect but when i press next second modal and third modal its automatically taking the fixed width size but i need to modify it. I tried ti declare width using modal dialog but it's width reflecting to step 1 modal. I need to make separate width for each modal.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row hide" data-step="1" data-title="" id="one">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <font color="black"> <a href="#" style="color: darkred">
                  <span style="color: darkred;">&times;</span>
                  </a></font>
                  </button>
                  <label class=" col-sm-4">Edit &nbsp;&nbsp; <span
                     type="text"><a href="#" id="item"
                     class="text js-btn-step" data-orientation="next">Save</a></span></label> <br />
                  <div class="container">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="form-body">
                              <br />
                              <table class="table table-responsive">
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td class="outside scrollable-menu"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          <select id="inputEducation" class="form-control"
                                             required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('State Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">10th</option>
                                             <option value="a">10th</option>
                                             <option value="b">12th</option>
                                             <option value="a">Degree</option>
                                             <option value="b">Masters</option>
                                             <option value="b">Cetificate</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                       <td class="outside scrollable-menu"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          <select id="inputStream" class="form-control" required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Stream Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">Degree</option>
                                             <option value="ar">BCA</option>
                                             <option value="cm">BSc</option>
                                             <option value="sc">BBA</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          Stream
                                          <select
                                             id="inputStream" class="form-control" required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Stream Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">Stream</option>
                                             <option value="ar">Arts</option>
                                             <option value="cm">Commerce</option>
                                             <option value="sc">Science</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          Institution
                                          <select id="inputStream" class="form-control" required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Stream Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">Institution</option>
                                             <option value="ar">VTU</option>
                                             <option value="cm">Anna</option>
                                             <option value="sc">Bangalore</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">Yr
                                          of Passing <input type="date" class="form-control"
                                             id="resizedTextbox" placeholder="Yr of Passing" />
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          State
                                          <select
                                             id="inputState" class="form-control" required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('State Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">State</option>
                                             <option value="is">Karnataka</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;">
                                          Country
                                          <select id="inputCountry" class="form-control" required
                                             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Country Required')"
                                             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
                                             <option hidden value="">Country</option>
                                             <option value="is">India</option>
                                             <option value="is">US</option>
                                          </select>
                                       </td>
                                       <td class="outside"
                                          style="border-style: none; border-bottom-style: none;"><br>
                                          <input type="file" size="80">
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row hide" data-step="2" id="two">
            <center>
               <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <center>Do you want add another record</center>
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning js-btn-step"
                     data-orientation="previous"
                     style="background-color: lightblue;">Yes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success js-btn-step"
                     data-orientation="next" style="background-color: lightblue;">No</button>
            </center>
            </div>
            </center>
         </div>
         <div class="row hide" data-step="3" id="three">
            <center>
               <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <center>NN records saved</center>
                  <br> <span class="btn btn-success js-btn-step"
                     data-orientation="Complete"
                     style="background-color: lightblue;">Ok</span> <br>
            </center>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code to remove unnecessary tabs in indentation. Also remove too many div based hierarchy so DOM structure is easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use different modals for each step, try changing their `max-width` like following.

```
#modalOne .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 300px;
}

#modalTwo .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

and so on.

Also add a `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute for each next button. It will close the current modal & opens next one.

**[Working example : JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/27574/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try set `width` by attribute `data-step`

```
.modal-content[data-step="2"]{
width://whatever you want
}
```